# Search for text with specific length and no spaces

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am just learning Access (2010) and I am trying to set the criteria for a query so that it only brings back names where the length is 10 letters and there are no spaces.

I tried `Len([Name])="10"` and that returns the names with a length of 10, but it also includes those names with a space in it.

The hint given was:

> Use the wildcards * and ?, and the phrases LIKE and NOT LIKE"

However that was not enough for me to sort it out.

What criteria would solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to solve this sort of issue, try this:

```
SELECT Communication.CommunicationCode, Communication.CommunicationName
FROM Communication
WHERE LEN([CommunicationCode])=10 AND CommunicationName NOT LIKE "* *"
```

You need to remove the quotes from the `10`.